# Reduce size of progress ring in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, progress

I am using the progress ring in an app, in Windows phone 8.1. I am not able to reduce the height and width beyond a specific value.

```
 How can I reduce the size of progress ring..?
```

I also would like to change the dots in progress ring to continuous ring, like a progress ring in Android. Is this possible..?

Answer (score 3):

The ProgressRing default template sets MinHeight and MinWidth to 20.

Find the default template by right clicking the control in the designer/outline and select template > edit a copy, or directly in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj709924.aspx).

There you will also find out that the ProgressRing is just a set of elipses animated with a storyboard. You cannot just change it to a full circle. (But you may create an own template with an animated circle.)